# ItemManager class has too many responsibilities (load items, give items, has a reference to ItemsList)

Tags: c#, single-responsibility

So my manager class does 2 things, load items from file and give one item to a thread that asks for it, it also holds the List that will contain all the items.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Bot.Core.MainEntryPoint
{
    class ItemManager
    {
        private static List<string> ItemsList = new List<string>();
        private static int Pos = 0;
        private static object LockObject = new object(); // multiple threads would be accessing this at the same time

    public static void LoadFromFile()
    {
        ItemsList = File.ReadAllLines("PATH TO FILE").ToList();
    }

    public static string GetOneItem()
    {
        string result = "";

        if (List.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                if (Pos > ItemsList.Count - 1)
                {
                    Pos = 0;
                }

                result = ItemsList[Pos];

                Pos++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Now in my opinion this violates the single responsibility principle and doesn't at the same time (seems to be relative to who uses it)

I tried having a ItemLoader class, a ItemGiver class, but then i can't figure out where i would be loading to or getting the items from, that "ItemsList" has to be somewhere.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. Its one responsibility is to manage an ItemManager object.

Comment: Obligatory Coding Horror post: [I Shall Call It... SomethingManager](https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/).

Comment: needs more statics

Comment: @Ewan i dont see any reason for this class to have a non static member.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc Then this just adds to my opinion that SRP is flawled to some point, its so relative.

Comment: Unrelated to the question - are you aware that the .NET framework offers a number of thread-safe collections such as  [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`BlockingCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview)?     Most of the code in this class would be redundant with either of those.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So there are a number of (potential) problems with this class. But yes, I agree it shouldn't load itself from a file.

Although you have a simple case here, actually there is quite a lot to worry about. What format is the file, is it on the local disk, do I get it from an api, do I also have to know how to write the file etc etc.

Split the file loading and saving into a separate repository class.

```
public class LoopedList
{
    public LoopedList(IEnumerable items) {...}
    public Item GetNext() {...}
}

public class ItemListRepository_File : IItemRepo
{
    public LoopedList GetItemList(string id) {...}
}
```

The reason you are finding it hard to seperate the two bits of code is because you have everything static. This prevents you from decoupling.

Have a singleton LoopedList in your App.Main if you must. But keep everything else as instance variables

Comment: what if i have a "KeywordsManager", "ProxiesManager", "UrlsManager", executing your idea and sticking the singletons in the main() seems a bit odd..

Comment: what seems odd about it to you?